# Is there a way to export the linear regression summaries from R as an image? I need to export the summaries as .jpeg or as .png

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to export the linear regression summary to a powerpoint slide by R using the "R2PPT" package. But there is no option to export ".txt" file into powerpoint, so only "jpeg" files will do. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package "Stargazer" would let you export the summary into beautifully formatted html, LaTex or plain ASCII text.
Just open the resulting html file in a browser, copy it as is or capture it as an image and paste it into your presentation.

```
library(stargazer)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(a = rnorm(30), b = rnorm(30)))
fit_lm <- lm(data, formula = a ~ b)
stargazer(fit_lm, type = "html", out = "fit_lm.html")
```

[PNG with the lm summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLKRt.png)