# Using Factanal, how would i turn the print data into an excel?

Tags: r

I'm using the code factanal() to run a factor analysis on a set of numbers. when i use print() on the data, it gives me the exact information I want, but i can not figure out a way to turn the print data into either an excel file or a table i can copy or paste etc.

I've tried to use the df%loadings method, which can be extracted in table format, but it only returns some of the data

```
x<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
x.fa <- factanal(x, 2, rotation = "promax")
print(x.fa, digits = 2, cutoff = .01, sort=TRUE)
load <- x.fa$loadings[,1:2]
```

the print() data produces:

```
Call:
factanal(x = x, factors = 2, rotation = "promax")

Uniquenesses:
  X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10 
0.99 0.99 0.94 0.91 0.98 0.70 0.99 0.94 1.00 0.99 

Loadings:
    Factor1 Factor2
X6   0.55   -0.03  
X1   0.08   -0.01  
X2   0.05   -0.05  
X3   0.07    0.23  
X4  -0.07    0.29  
X5  -0.08    0.14  
X7  -0.08   -0.05  
X8  -0.05   -0.24  
X9  -0.02    0.03  
X10  0.10          

               Factor1 Factor2
SS loadings       0.34    0.22
Proportion Var    0.03    0.02
Cumulative Var    0.03    0.06

Factor Correlations:
        Factor1 Factor2
Factor1  1.0000 -0.0083
Factor2 -0.0083  1.0000

Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 14.72 on 26 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.962
```

but loadings will only produce:

```
        Factor1      Factor2
X1   0.08177105 -0.013743649
X2   0.05234575 -0.051777196
X3   0.07254985  0.225662681
X4  -0.07258327  0.290420749
X5  -0.07659875  0.137909308
X6   0.54611007 -0.031340439
X7  -0.07808143 -0.050940296
X8  -0.05255525 -0.243979047
X9  -0.02006703  0.030441980
X10  0.09628584  0.006476054
```

Comment: If you wanted to write this to file, one option is `capture.output(x.fa, file = "yourfile.txt")`

Comment: Do you know of a way to turn the data into something that can be read on excel?

Comment: If you can show what your expected output, it would be useful.  `broom::tidy(x.fa)` will get some info

Comment: or `glance(x.fa)`, but without what you expect as output, it is not easier to suggest

Comment: The expected output would be all the information in the print() data except able to be exported or treated like a table. I have many different subsets that need to have a factor analysis ran on, and i need to be able to put them all in a single excel file on separate tabs.

Comment: In that case, you can use `capture.output`

Comment: Or you can also do extract some of the individual components `x.fa$uniqueness` or `x.fa$correlation` and write

Comment: Would there be a way to turn the print() data into a Jpg?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463212/is-there-a-way-to-export-the-linear-regression-summaries-from-r-as-an-image-i-n)